# SQL query how to find the average number of rental days per years

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Books(RegNum, BookName, Category)
Rental(RegNum, clientID, DateBorrowed, DateReturned)
```

I want to list all the books name and their average number if rental days per year. However, the type of DateBorrowed and DateReturned is DATE something like 2020-01-07. How can i calculate the average rental days for each book. I am new to SQL. I would be appreacite if anyone could give me some ideas.

Right now I'm trying this.

```
SELECT Books.RegNum, Books.BooksName, AVG(DATEDIFF(Rental.DateReturned, Rental.DateBorrowed)) AS AvgRentalDay
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Rental
ON Books.RegNum = Rental.RegNum
GROUP BY Books.RegNum;
```

But I think I’m calculating the average date rental days for each books (at least I think I am). Any suggestion for how to calculate the average rental days per year?

Comment: You may start with [MySql date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Serg has the right idea. You probably want to use a DateDiff function for each rental, then make a group by.  In the [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) you can make an aggregate of rental dates.  Then join it to the book table for your solution. You should split this up in pieces to better understand how to build a query like this.

1. Understand Date functions
2. Understand GroupBy
3. Understand aggregate functions from GroupBy
4. Join the tables

In the future, show some of the work that you did to solve it, or what issue you're running into. That way we're not just giving you the solution when we don't know if you even tried

**"Any suggestion for how to calculate the average rental days per year"**
You can group by deeper values if you need to. Genre for example.  Just make sure that any value in the `SELECT` is in the `GROUP BY` unless it's an aggregate function.

I added `Books.BooksName` to the group by to make sure it works.  But that looks like it should work

```
SELECT Books.RegNum, 
    Books.BooksName, 
    YEAR(Rental.DateBorrowed) AS Year, 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(Rental.DateReturned, Rental.DateBorrowed)) AS AvgRentalDay
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Rental
ON Books.RegNum = Rental.RegNum
GROUP BY Books.RegNum, Books.BooksName, YEAR(Rental.DateBorrowed);
```

Comment: Yeah. Of course. Thank you for your advices. I just don't know where to start. The DateDiff is exactly I'm looking for. Right now I am trying this DateDiff function. I have updated my question above. Any suggestion on how to improve my current answer?

Comment: @Amber_ I updated the respnse. If you just want to group only by year, and not by books, you can remove the Books references in the group by, keeping the YEAR function